# Chrome Extensions and RSS feeds

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a chrome extension for a site that amongst the other stuff displays the latest RSS feed item. I've tried various libraries but they all rely on remote scripts. I was wondering if:

A) There is a way to bypass the security in the extensions.

Or

B) There are any alternatives.

Comment: What security would you need to get around? You can set in the manifest.json file the ability to make ajax requests to other domains. What exactly are you having issues with in getting the RSS from the site?

Comment: "I've tried various libraries but they all rely on remote scripts." <-- as in, they do `<script src='http://example.com/blah.js'></script>`